# How to filter array in json object with computed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```javascript
fetchData() {
      axios.get("api_url").then((response) => {
        this.dataArr = response.data;
      });
    },
```

I can't do `this.dataArr = response.data.items.fruits;` because I need to use this somewhere else like this.

`dataArr` looks like this:

```javascript
{
   "items":{
      "fruits":[
         {
            "name":"banana",
            "type":"fruit",
    
         },
         {
            "name":"kiwi",
            "type":"fruit",
    
         },
  ]
}
```

I am trying to filter this in computed property:

```javascript
filterData(){
   return this.dataArr.filter((item) => item.name )
}
```

But I am getting an error saying that `this.dataArr` is not a function, I need to get access to `this.dataArr.items.fruits`, but when I write it like that it's not working. Is there way to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting "this.dataArr is not a function"? Is doesn't make sense that using `.filter()` on `this.dataArr` would throw that error- [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is an array prototype function.

Answer (score 1):

You should get access to the nested `fruits` array and it seems that you're trying to map that array by returning only the names in this case use `map` method:

```
 filterData(){
     if(this.dataArr.items && this.dataArr.items.fruits){
      return this.dataArr.items.fruits.map((item) => item.name )
      }else{
        return []
     }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work like that.
Even when I try to compute ```return this.dataArr.items```
and then do a v-for in html with this computed it wont display anything

Comment: Yes but I think the issue is because I used nuxt.js